# Is there a way to show previous query results in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I ran a few queries in SQL Developer and closed the query result panel after i looked through the data. I have then deleted the data but now im trying to see if I can find/view the data i viewed somehow?

is there a way to find the data i viewed?

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as I know, SQL Developer has no feature that saves results of previous queries.

Answer (score 0):

Once you close them, they are 'gone.'

But, you can setup SQLDev not to close the results as you execute new queries. Benefit, you have to explicitly close the panel before you 'lose' the results.

[image]

Warning: Close these tabs as you can. They tie up potentially both CLIENT and SERVER side resources.

*Disclaimer: I work for Oracle and am the product manager for SQL Developer.*